# Game Center Not Recognizing my game

Tags: iphone, xcode, game-center

I am making a test app to learn using Game Center. I've read many tutorials and questions here in stack overflow and i'm on the right way.

Now, i have met a behaviour i don't understand and i thought someone might shed some more light upon it and solve my problem.

I have created a user from the Game Center on the simulator and i am able to enter into it.

If i'm logged into it, and then run my app i get the wonderful "Welcome back" sign from game center.

But when i log out of there it acts differently. I start my app and get the login form. When trying to log in i get a UIAlert that says the "This game is not recognized by game center".

How come? A minute ago everything went smooth…

Anyway, i tried checking the bundle identifier on iTunes connect and on my app, i checked that game center is supported on the iTunes connect. I even created a group (although i'm not sure what it means yet).

Nothing works. (except logging to game center before starting the app)

Any thoughts?

Let me know if you need any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK… This is solved now. The main issue was the bundle ID.

One place showed: com.myCompanyName.gameName
and the other: myCompanyName.gameName

The .com is what i missed.

Thank to all those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Very first thing you have to enable Game Center for your App_ID from apple.developer.com
.Next thing you need to make use of same App_ID as Bundle ID while creating App on iTunes Connect. And I hope you have added details of Game Center in that app on iTunes Connect. Also be sure you are using provisioning profile with same Bundle ID.